# How to fix a warning about undefined array key in php caused by window.history.replaceState?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, error-handling, warnings

I have a js code in my head tag to prevent popups about resubmitting the form. It works, but it caused an error message in my select input (sorting items).
This is the js code:

```
if (window.history.replaceState){
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Sort:
    <select name="Sort" onchange="form.submit();" id="sort">
        
        <optgroup label="Alphabetically">
            <option value="alphabet_p" <?php if($_POST['Sort'] == 'alphabet_p') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>> 
                A-Z
            </option>

            <option value="alphabet_rev_p" <?php if($_POST['Sort'] == 'alphabet_rev_p') {echo "selected=selected"; } ?>>
                Z-A
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</form>
```

PHP (there is some other stuff):

```
function recipe_list_dishes() {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
    $sort = $_POST["Sort"];

    switch ($sort) {
        case "alphabet_p":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name";
        break;
            
        case "alphabet_rev_p":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE type = $dish_type ORDER BY name DESC";
        break;

    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Of course I removed some stuff that (at least I think so) is not important in this problem.
This is the warning message (it shows up in the "select" box):
Warning: Undefined array key "Sort" in [xampp path] on line 129 > A-Z (line 129 is the first  tag in HTML).
Everything seems to work fine without js. I can't put it in the body tag next to the footer, because it won't work.
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your query is insecure/unstable.  Please read about the importance of prepared statements.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63523103/2943403

Answer (score 1):

There's no `$_POST` variables when the page is loaded without submitting the form. So check if it's set:

```
if(isset($_POST['Sort']) && $_POST['Sort'] == 'alphabet_p')
```

Comment: Now it resets my select tag to A-Z (first option) when I refresh the page :/